# Script no longer works after pytoexe conversion

Tags: python, exe, py2exe, traceback

I have created a script in python that you can find attached, if I run it from visual code it works perfectly, but if I convert it with `pytoexe` I get the error shown below.

I installed the packages in the virtual environment where I saved the script

```
        ############# USER FINDER ##############

        userfinder = soup.find('span', class_='ivupad-user-first-name')
        user = (userfinder.text)

        ############# USER FINDER ##############

scraping()
while True:
    scraping()
    if input("Möchtest du fortfahren? Weiter mit 'j' oder 'n'").strip().upper() != 'j':
        break
driver.close()
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Monatseint_Tool_v0.5.py", line 349, in <module>
  File "Monatseint_Tool_v0.5.py", line 86, in scraping
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
[4144] Failed to execute script 'Monatseint_Tool_v0.5' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: There's too much code here. Please pare it down to a [repro]. FWIW, it looks like you have a block where you retrieve the `.text` attribute of six separate `soupdata` elements. One of them is probably `None`, so the you get this error.

Comment: The error says it is in this block, but from the terminal it works correctly...


 userfinder = soup.find('span', class_='ivupad-user-first-name')
        user = (userfinder.text)

Comment: Can you try putting your exe where the python file is located so they are in the same folder ? Or try adding at the most bottom of your code `input()` then convert it again and check if it works or not ? The reason of adding `input()` is to make the program keep working and closes unless you close it yourself.

Comment: i added the input() code on the bottom as suggested and tried to run the exe file in the same folder where is the py files saved but i had the same errorr..